# Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

Below is the code written in my get method. I don't know why am I facing this problem. How to solve it , please provide some code.

```
app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    https.get(url,function(response)
    {
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data",function(data)
        {
            const apidata = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(apidata)
        })
    })

})
```

Comment: Try to log the `data` on the debug console: `console.log(data)`. Most likely it is not valid JSON what you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing this problem because `response.on('data', ...` is a stream which means you likely don't have the full json object yet, which also means you're trying to parse a partial response. You should collect the json chunks in `on('data', ...` and then parse the json when the response is complete. Something like this:

```js
https.get(url, function(response){
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  let rawData = ''
  response.on("data", function(data){
    rawData = `${rawData}${data}`
  })
  response.on("end", function() {
    const apidata = JSON.parse(rawData)
    console.log(apidata)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Response from https.get are already JSON object, you don't need to parse it.